# Laravel - Passing data from multiple methods from the same controller to a partial view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7

I have a simple phone book application with a main view, **index.blade.php** that includes a partial view, **contact_list.blade.php**.

I only have a single route that refers to my controller, **ContactListController.php**.

From inside **contact_list.blade.php** I need access to three methods of my controller.

One of the methods returns the data I need to pass as parameter for the other two.

Here's what my application looks like so far:

[image]

I want to be able to type a name in the search form and then filter the names of usuarios in the **contact_list** view.

Here's **search_contact.blade.php**, where the search form is located:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 inp">
    <form action="." method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="searchName" id="searchName" class="form-control mt-2 mb-3" placeholder="search">
            <input class="btn btn-info w-100 btn1" type="submit" value="search">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's **contact_list.blade.php**:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">

    <table id="myTable" class="table text-justify table-striped">
        <thead class="tableh1">
            <th class="">Name</th>
            <th class="col-3">Nº of Phones</th>
            <th class="">Phones</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="tableBody">

            @if (!isset($_GET["searchName"]))
            @foreach ($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <!-- Test -->
                <td>{{ $item->nome }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->numero_count }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <?php $phones = app\Http\Controllers\ContactListController::get_telefones_by_usuario($item->u_id) ?>
                        @foreach ($phones as $phone)
                        <li><i class="bi bi-telephone-fill pe-2" style="color: #0d6efd"></i>{{ $phone->numero }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @else
            <?php $my_data = app\Http\Controllers\ContactListController::get_users_by_name(request()) ?>

            @foreach ($my_data as $item)
            <tr>
                <!-- Test -->
                <td>{{ $item->nome }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->numero_count }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <?php $phones = app\Http\Controllers\ContactListController::get_telefones_by_usuario($item->u_id) ?>
                        @foreach ($phones as $phone)
                        <li><i class="bi bi-telephone-fill pe-2" style="color: #0d6efd"></i>{{ $phone->numero }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here are my three methods inside my controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        // $usuarios = Usuario::all();
        // $telefones = Telefone::all();
        $data = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->get();

        return view("index", compact("data"));
    }
```

```
    public static function get_telefones_by_usuario($id)
    {

        $telefones = Telefone::join("usuarios", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select("telefones.numero as numero")
            ->where("usuarios.id", "=", $id)
            ->get();

        return $telefones;
        // return view("index", compact("telefones"));
    }
```

```
    public static function get_users_by_name(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input("searchName");

        $usuarios = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->where("usuarios.nome", "LIKE", "$" . $name . "%")
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->get();

        return $usuarios;
    }
```

I call my controller method from inside the partial view, but I heard it's bad practice to do that. If that's the case, then how can I achieve what I want?

My idea was to access the GET parameter `searchName` (from the form inside **search_contact.blade.php** partial view) from within my **contact_list** view, by calling the controller method. But I'm getting zero results back with my code as it is:

[image]

How can I achieve what I want? What am I doing wrong?

Is it really that bad to call a controller method from inside a view? If so, what can I do instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {               
        $data = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->get();

        $search =  $request->input('pick');
        if($search!=""){
            $data= Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")->where(function ($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('nome', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere('numero', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');                    
            })
            ->get();
            $data->appends(['pick' => $search]);
        } else {
            $data = Usuario::join("telefones", "usuarios.id", "=", "telefones.id_usuario")
            ->select(
                "usuarios.id as u_id",
                "usuarios.nome as nome",
                "telefones.numero as numero",
                DB::raw("COUNT(telefones.numero) AS numero_count")
            )
            ->groupBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->orderBy("usuarios.nome")
            ->get();        
        }
        
        return return view("index", compact("data"));
    }
```

**view**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 inp">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="pick" id="searchName" class="form-control mt-2 mb-3" placeholder="search">
            <input class="btn btn-info w-100 btn1" type="submit" value="search">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```